# Communication between apps in same app service plan?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

To clarify what I'm **not** asking about, there's alot of documentation about using endpoints to expose apps in a App Service Plan to a vnet, which is useful for private communication between vnet hosted VMs or other resources **outside** the app service plan.

What I'm asking about is specifically communication between two apps **inside** the same app service plan.  So if we had PlanA, and AppB and AppC both deployed to that plan, then if PlanA scales to two instances, each instance would have both AppB and AppC inside it.  Very similar to an IIS farm hosting multiple applications.

If I want to disable public access for AppC, but still allow AppB to call AppC(imagine if AppC is a API service and AppB is a front end web app), is that possible?  How would you resolve that call if the AppC doesn't have a public IP?  Would the domain `appC.azurewebsites.net` resolve to a privateIP that AppB can access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that two app services run in one app service plan means only that these app services can share the same set of computing resources (CPU, memory, etc.) and it does not provide any network isolation or private IP addresses within an app service plan.

If you want to keep the existing setup and restrict access to AppC, you can whitelist IP addresses of AppB as follows:

1. Go to the **AppB** in Azure Portal, click **Properties** and copy the list of **Outbound IP addresses**.
2. Go to the **AppC**, click **Networking** -> **Access Restrictions** and deny access to everything apart from the outbound IP addresses you copied in step 1.

The domain `appC.azurewebsites.net` will still have a public IP address but Azure will only allow accessing it from the IP addresses you configured and return 403 error to any other client.

However, if you want to have a truly private endpoint and more granular control over routing configuration, then consider integrating your app services with Azure virtual network as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration). Virtual networks are not limited to VMs, they can be used for app services too.